# Why does JavaScript seem to return modulus inconsistently?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning `JavaScript` and I have a page that displays the result of dividing two user-inputted numbers.

I didn't like that `(1 / 3)` would fill the whole result box with `3.333333333333...`, so I set the result with `.toFixed(4)`. But this has the result of making `(4 / 2)` return `2.0000` instead of just `2`.

So, in order to fix that I check if `(answer % 1 == 0)`, in which case it displays the answer normally, then checks `(answer % 0.1 == 0)`, which displays `answer.toFixed(1)`, and so on, with the final `else` being `.toFixed(4)`.

This works as intended for some numbers but not for others, and I don't see why or what's going wrong in the cases it doesn't work.

**Examples:**

- `(2 / 5)` returns `0.4`. This satisfies the second condition, `(answer % 0.1 == 0)`, and returns `answer.toFixed(1)`, displaying `0.4`. Great.
- `(2 / 10)` also works and displays `0.2`, and something like `(2 / 7)` correctly gets pushed to the `else` and displays `0.2857`.
- `(2 / 8)` returns `0.25`, then incorrectly displays `0.2500`
- `(2 / 20)` correctly returns and displays `0.1`
- `(9 / 6)` returns `1.5`, then incorrectly displays `1.5000`
- `(2 / 4)` returns `0.5`, but displays `0.5000`. It failed all the conditions and jumps to the `else` sentence, so `answer.toFixed(4)` is used.

Why does JavaScript consider `(0.4 % 0.1 == 0)` to be `true`, but `(0.5 % 0.1 == 0)` to be `false`?

This is my current code:

```
let num1 = parseFloat($("calcInput1").value);
let num2 = parseFloat($("calcInput2").value);
answer = num1 / num2;

if (answer % 1 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("calcResult").value = answer;
    alert("answer % 1 == 0");
} else if (answer % 0.1 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("calcResult").value = answer.toFixed(1);
    alert("answer % 0.1 == 0");
} else if (answer % 0.01 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("calcResult").value = answer.toFixed(2);
    alert("answer % 0.01 == 0");
} else if (answer % 0.001 == 0) {
    document.getElementById("calcResult").value = answer.toFixed(3);
    alert("else");
} else {
    document.getElementById("calcResult").value = answer.toFixed(4);
}
```

Comment: Because it's Javascript?  Or maybe because Javascript uses double-precision floating point?  This question is very difficult to read; do you think maybe you could clean it up a bit?

Comment: It isn't because it is JavaScript @Robert, that is a bit naive. This Java code will produce the same result: `System.out.println((0.25 % 0.01));` It is simply a well understood floating point mathematics dilemma.
`

Comment: @barmar - It's not clear to me that that's what the OP's talking about. In particular, the question *""* isn't significantly impacted by floating point imprecision.

Comment: `0.4 % 0.1 == 0` is true because `0.4 % 0.1` is `0`. `0.5 % 0.1 == 0` is false because `0.5 % 0.1` is `0.09999999999999998` (very near `0.1`), which isn't `== 0`, so...false. Why do you find these `== 0` results surprising? It's also probably worth noting that `%` isn't modulus, it's [remainder](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator), though I *think* that's a distinction that doesn't come into the positive values above...

Comment: @RandyCasburn: I was not entirely serious.

Comment: @Zachary221334 Because `0.2` and `0.1` can't be represented exactly in floating point, so roundoff errors are introduced when you calculate the modulus.

Comment: By analogy, `0.666666 % 0.333333 == 0`, but `1.000000 % 0.333333 == 0.000001`.

Comment: How about `answer.toFixed(4).replace(/0+$/, '')`? Or even `String(Math.round(1e4 * answer) / 1e4)` – that’s weirdly reliable.

Comment: So when doing math 0.5 is treated as 0.49999999, even though when I populate a textbox with that variable it has no problem displaying it as 0.5...

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that what you need to output can be achieved using:

```
var answer = +(num1 / num2).toFixed(4);
```

Casting the `string` generated with `toFixed()` back to a `number` can help to avoid the redundant zeros at the end. Also, you don't need to use the `modulus` operator at all and do not need to face the problems related to arithmetics precision with floating point.

Note I have use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to cast the string back to number, as on the `MDN` says:

> Unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number.

## Example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("calc");
var in1 = document.getElementById("calcInput1");
var in2 = document.getElementById("calcInput2");
var out = document.getElementById("answer");

button.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    var num1 = in1.value, num2 = in2.value;
    var answer = +(num1 / num2).toFixed(4);
    out.value = answer;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="calcInput1">
<input type="text" id="calcInput2">
<button type="button" id="calc">Calc</button>
<input type="text" id="answer">
```

Comment: How is this relevant? You need to explain how this answers the question.

Comment: @LukeSalamone Sorry for that, I see the duplicate mark when was making the answer and has to post it without explanation.